# Could Func<TResult> and Func<T, TResult> have 1 name in method signature?

Tags: c#-4.0, func

I have 2 methods:

```
private static async Task<T> GetInfoAsync<T>(MyClient service, Func<Task<T>> funcAsync, string resultText)
    {
        var result = default(T);

        if (service != null) {
            try {
                service.Open();
                result = await funcAsync();
                service.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(resultText);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                service.Abort();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static async Task<T> GetInfoAsync<T>(MyClient service, Func<string,Task<T>> funcAsync, string resultText, string param)
    {
        var result=default(T);

        if (service != null) {
            try {
                service.Open();
                result = await funcAsync(param);
                service.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(resultText);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                service.Abort();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Is is possible to create 1 method for 2 functions?
Something like 
"private static async Task GetInfoAsync(MyClient service,  Something??, string resultText, string param)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but in general you can do a partial function (see for example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/01/29/currying-and-partial-function-application.aspx) that, given a function with a parameter, calls it with a fixed value for that parameter.

```
// The original function
Func<string, Task<T>> fullFunction = x => ...;

// The partial function
string param = "...";
Func<Task<T>> partialFunction = () => fullFunction(param);
```

So it would be the caller of `GetInfoAsync` that would need to create this `partialFunction` and pass it to `GetInfoAsync`.